# how to SQL for getting the Grand total from SUM of 2 fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This the sql I created

```
SELECT SUM(SupplierItems.SupplierItemCost +
           SupplierItems.SupplierItemInventory
          ) AS TotalCost
FROM SupplierItems 
GROUP BY SupplierItems.ID
```

The sql above is getting you the sum of two fields which is itemcost and iteminventory, and this is the result

```
TotalCost
1000
2000
3000
```

I Need to get the SUM of all from TotalCost.

Thanks,

Comment: Remove the `GROUP BY` and you'll get the sum for the entire table.

Comment: @stickybit looks like your correct ^_^ thanks

Comment: You need SUM for the entire table or SUM per a group?

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the sum of all TotalCost's at the additional row, you can use `ROLLUP`.

```
SELECT SupplierItems.ID, SUM(SupplierItems.SupplierItemCost +
           SupplierItems.SupplierItemInventory
          ) AS TotalCost
FROM SupplierItems 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(SupplierItems.ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the total sum in the table, then remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SUM(si.SupplierItemCost +
           si.SupplierItemInventory
          ) AS TotalCost
FROM SupplierItems si;
```

Be careful, though.  If any of the underlying values are `NULL`, then you may not get the correct result.  It is safer to do:

```
SELECT (COALESCE(SUM(si.SupplierItemCost), 0) +
        COALESCE(SUM(si.SupplierItemInventory, 0)
       ) AS TotalCost
FROM SupplierItems si;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want grand total then you can use without **GROUP BY**

```
SELECT SUM(SupplierItems.SupplierItemCost +
           SupplierItems.SupplierItemInventory
          ) AS TotalCost
FROM SupplierItems
```

if you want partial total based on **SupplierItems.ID** then you can use **GROUP BY**

```
SELECT SupplierItems.ID,SUM(SupplierItems.SupplierItemCost +
           SupplierItems.SupplierItemInventory
          ) AS TotalCost
FROM SupplierItems 
GROUP BY SupplierItems.ID
```